# How can I convert a BIN and a CUE file to an ISO image on Linux?

Tags: linux, iso-image, disk-image

I downloaded two disk images files on the Internet Archive that contain operating systems installation files.
I have a .BIN and a .CUE, and I want to convert them to a single ISO.

I tried using `bchunk image.bin image.cue image.iso` but instead of giving `image.iso`, it gave me `image.iso001.cdr`.

So I tried to convert the .CDR file to a .ISO, but the only software I found to do this is `hdiutil` and it is only available on MacOS...

Can someone help please?

Comment: I have never used `bchunk`, but the description in the [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bchunk) makes me believe if you only got `.cdr`, it means in the input files there was only music in the native CD audio format; no ISO9660 nor similar *filesystem*, i.e. nothing to make an `.iso` from. Not tested, not confirmed, therefore not an answer, just a comment.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but I really think its not a audio disk because the file name is literally "Windows 2000.bin" and "Windows 2000.cue", I downloaded it from here: https://archive.org/download/windows-20th-anniversary-edition-microsoft-japan/Discs/Replica%20CDs/      these were uploaded by BetaCollector

Comment: Even Toast can't make sense of those files. It thinks it's an audio CD. This one, on the other hand, mounts fine - https://archive.org/details/enwin2000prosp4_202001 pic - https://i.stack.imgur.com/XX0cO.png I'd just give up on the first one.

Comment: Check your `.cue` with a text editor. The file literally states the only track is `AUDIO`. I don't know why; I don't know if it's a mistake. It *seems* wrong, but I know too little to be sure. Anyway, I think this is the direct reason why you got a `.cdr.`.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - thanks for the extra legwork. I'm used to Toast being "the authority" on CDs etc so had come to a similar conclusion when it wanted to convert to an Sd2f file [an old sound designer audio format from which audio CDs were first built], which was then happily opened by an audio editor, & showed an hour of a single sine wave. The image is, to put it politely, borked.

Comment: Really weird, its show that the file is an AUDIO track.
```
FILE "Windows 2000.bin" BINARY
  TRACK 01 AUDIO
    INDEX 01 00:00:00
```
Can I modify the CUE file to make that it convert the BIN file gave me the ISO file I want ? Or does there is any other way to convert my BIN file (and CUE file) to the ISO ? I will try to convert the BIN file to ISO and ignore the CUE file... Not sure this will work.

Comment: OK, what I tried does not work.
I tried this: 
`genisoimage -o Windows\ 2000.iso Windows\ 2000.bin`
The command worked, but the result is not what I wanted.
It just... Compressed the file as ISO.